# How to get return prices for a one way ticket?

Tags: air-travel, budget, one-way

I am emigrating to the USA from the UK and need to purchase a flight. I have noticed that direct one way flights are over £1000 and return flights are only just over £500. Is there any way to get the price for a return ticket for a one way? If not, are there any repercussions for not using the return flight? I have a visa and everything is above board, I just don't want to spend the £500 extra when I can just buy a return for half the price of a direct one way.

Comment: Basically, yes, you can just buy the return - but if you do it lots, the airline may ping you or cancel your FF status.  Some also argue it's morally wrong. We've had this asked before, so I've closed it as a duplicate - there's some good info in that question too.

Comment: Here are some tips for this specific case: There are some airlines that do cheap one-ways. Virgin Atlantic, for example has them, and probably Icelandair. Since they only serve few destinations, you may have to combine them "by hand" with a domestic separate US-domestic ticket after a long-enough layover at a suitable US airport - domestic US tickets are often available for reasonable single-trip fares, too. However, this combination is a bit risky as you will lose the domestic flight if your incoming flight is delayed.